# How to access Foreign Fields in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I'm a beginner with Django. I have a set of tables with relationships defined in my models, and I am looking to retrieve linked values in the front end. I'm unable to find out how to do this, and would appreciate help.

I can currently see something that looks like this, where 1 is the key of the currency EUR in the Currency table:

```
Spend Amount | Spend Currency
10           | 1
```

I instead want it to look like this:

```
Spend Amount | Spend Currency
10           | EUR
```

**Models**

```
class Currency (models.Model):
    currCode = models.CharField('Currency',max_length=3)
    currName = models.CharField('Name',max_length=100)

class Spend (models.Model):
    spendAmount = models.DecimalField('Amount', max_digits=12,decimal_places=2)
    spendCurrency = models.ForeignKey(Currency)
```

**Views**

```
from .models import Spend

def all_spends(request):
    spend_list = Spend.objects.all()
    return render(request,
                  'spends/spend_list.html',
                  {'spend_list': spend_list})
```

**HTML Template**

```
{% for spend in spend_list %}
            <tr>             
                <th>{{ spend.spendAmount }}</th>
                <th>{{ spend.spendCurrency }}</th>
            </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Just update this `<th>{{ spend.spendCurrency }}</th>` line with this `<th>{{ spend.spendCurrency.currCode }}</th>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly from your template, you can access directly your Currency model using the foreign key field to display the desired field, in your case Currency.currName to display:

```
Spend Amount | Spend Currency
10           | EUR
```

In HTML template

```
<table>
    </thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Spend Amount</th>
            <th>Spend Currency</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
{% for spend in spend_list %}
    <tr>             
        <td>{{ spend.spendAmount }}</td>
        <td>{{ spend.spendcurrency.currName }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Note that it also exists a Django "[related manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/relations/#related-objects-reference)" or "[Backward relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward)" to access Spend from Currency. For example:

```
{{  my_currency.spend_set.spendAmount }}
```